# Spring Transactions not working (JDBC and Tomcat)

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions, spring-jdbc

I am trying to incorporate Spring transactions into my project, and it seems that they are not working. I went through some tutorials nad Spring docs, and for me everything seems OK.

What I have:
1) context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="webapp.dataaccess.commons.JdbcTemplateProvider">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- dao section -->

<bean id="modesDao" class="webapp.dataaccess.opcalc.basicdao.CalcModesData">
    <property name="jdbc" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>

<!-- lots of DAO beans defined same way -->
```

2) data source defined on server:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/calc_webapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="user" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/service" defaultAutoCommit = "true" />
```

3) and finally in one of the DAO beans I have this method:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Boolean saveFullOrganization(OrganizationLevel org) throws Exception{
    Boolean out = true;
    try{
        Integer adminPermKey = permDao.saveAdminPermissions(org.getPermissions().getAdminPermission());
        org.getPermissions().setAdminPermissionKey(adminPermKey);
        Integer sellPermKey = permDao.saveSellingPermissions(org.getPermissions().getSellingPermission());
        org.getPermissions().setSellingPermissionKey(sellPermKey);
        Integer dszPermKey = permDao.saveDszPermissions(org.getPermissions().getDszPermission());
        org.getPermissions().setDszPermissionKey(dszPermKey);
        Integer reportPermKey = permDao.saveReportingPermissions(org.getPermissions().getReportingPermission());
        org.getPermissions().setReportingPermissionKey(reportPermKey);

        if(org.getPermissions().getKey()==null){
            Integer permissions = permDao.savePermissionsSet(org.getPermissions(), null);
            org.setPermissionsKey(permissions);
        }
        saveOrganizationUnit(org, org.getKey());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Flow is rather intuitive - first part of method prepares permission entries for organization unit (each operation in bean permDao is also transactional), then finally calls "saveOrganizationUnit" to finalize adding new entry. I assumed that with transaction management if any exception occure in the middle of that procedure, then no data from it will go to DB. But my tests proved that if I trigger artificial exception before "saveOrganizationUnit" operation (which interrupts whole process nad jumps out of the method) the permission part lands in DB anyway. So, as I understand, transactions are not working in my solution.

I am not sure what should I check and what can be wrong (I am kind of Spring noob, so please, don't kick if its something obvious).

Comment: Where and how is your DataSource defined in the Spring context file? How do you get an instance of your DAO from your service, and how do you get an instance to your service?

Comment: Data source is defined as JNDI resource on server (and generally works). In my application I am not using additional service layer, application uses DAO directly (dirty, but efficient). I ma taking beans instances from Spring ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default behavour of `@Transactional` is defined [as follows](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.

So, I guess you are throwing a checked exception. If you want to trigger rollback in this case, you need to configure `@Transactional` accordingly:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class) ...
```